# Java error "Cannot find symbol"

Tags: java, awt

```
public class EasyPopup extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    BufferedReader buff = null;
    String wordlist[];
    wordlist=new String[66];
    int i=0;
    try {
        buff = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("easy.txt"));
        wordlist[i] = buff.readLine();
        while (wordlist[i] != null & i < 69) {
            i++;
            wordlist[i]=buff.readLine();
        }
    }
    catch(StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    finally {
        try{
            buff.close();
        } catch(IOException e1) { e1.printStackTrace(); }
    }
    String word = wordlist[new Random().nextInt(wordlist.length)];
    System.out.println("Your word: "+word+"");
}
```

I've a file to be read when the frame is created. A while later in the code, there is a ActionPerformed statement which uses the string word. However, it doesn't seem to work - saying "cannot find symbol." The ActionPerformed code is below.

```
private void btnTActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    btnT.setEnabled(false);       
    if (word.charAt(2)=="t") {
```

Anyone have an idea why this is occurring?

Comment: `word.charAt(2)=="t"` Incompatible operand types char and String. Use `'t'`.

Comment: Where does `word` come from? It is not in scope, I guess. + what icza sais.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace?  What line does it get the error on?

Comment: The error is on the `if(word.charAt(2)=="t"){` line, where word is underlined.

`Word` comes from the first chunk of code, in the line: `String word = wordlist[new Random().nextInt(wordlist.length)];`

Comment: Recheck your braces, I bet that's a scoping issue. Michael Piefel edited the code snipped. Before there were two `{` at the beginning...

Comment: At the beginning of where, sorry?

Comment: After the class declaration. I don't know if it was a typo but the original snippet had `public class EasyPopup extends javax.swing.JFrame { { `

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that this is a compiler error and not runtime. If that assumption is correct then I'd say the problem is that the variable word is not defined in the scope of that method. Although there are many possible solutions, moving the declaration of word to the class would be simplest.

Comment: Moving the declaration of word to what class?

Answer (score 0):

If `word` is not a class variable and you do not pass `word` as a parameter (which is obviously the case here), the variable `word` is out of scope and thus an unknown symbol to the compiler.

Check if you have declared `word` in the correct scope (class level).

Like:

```
public class EasyPopup /* Interfaces go here*/{
    private String word = "default"; // just a Default value, set it for example in ctor

    // other stuff here

    private void btnTActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        btnT.setEnabled(false);       
        if(word.charAt(2)=='t'){  // corrected already according to icza's comment , +1 for him
            // ...
        }
}
```

By the way there are more issues to your codesnippet. You cannot issue `System.out.println` on class Level. It has to be in some method. This will also create a compiletime error.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "Check if you have declared `word` in the correct scope (class level).

Comment: I wanted to say: If you put an additional set of `{` and `}`, this forms a block. Variables declared in that block are known only in that block, not outside. When your controlflow leaves the block, the variable goes "out of scope" and will not be seen.